# Regex Group Match help

Tags: regular-expression

Using this regex `;(31055\d*)|^;\d{10}(\d{7})` How do I get the second part of the regex after the "|" to report as Group 1 using the test string of `;1000000000146691301?` The regex is working but I need the `;1000000000144691301?` to match to `1446913` in Group 1 not group 2. I need both matches to come out in group 1. The first part of the regex works using `;3105540001042017?` and reports in Group 1.

Comment: Give concrete example what you are trying to achieve, it looks like XY problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sed regexp text processing capture grouping referencing alternation confusion](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/441084)

Comment: please make your question more clear. however _sed_ is perfect tools to grouping the **regex** pattern

Answer (score 0):

How about `(?|;(31055\d*)|^;\d{10}(\d{7}))`

This requires Branch Reset Group which is not available in JavaScript, so depending on what language you are using, it may not work.

Working example: https://regexr.com/3tlk1

Comment: Note that [that operator comes from `perl`](https://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.perl5.porters/2007/02/msg120671.html)